# Apache2 cannot bind to socket, and httpd cannot be killed

Tags: server, apache2

I recently missed a payment on my VPS, and when i reactivated it the apache server isn't working correctly.

I have a setup with various sites, seperated by subdomains (cloud.mydomain.com, wiki.mydomain.com etc.) and of course a mydomain.com front page.

After the reactivation, all my subdomains point to cloud.mydomain.com, which is running nextcloud. I find it wierd it does not atleast point to my usual frontpage.

Starting apache produces the following result:

```
$sudo service apache2 stop
$sudo service apache2 start
$sudo service apache2 status

Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]:  *
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4430]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4430]:  *
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

the output of netstat is:

```
$sudo service apache2 stop
$sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3979/httpd
```

killing the process produces the following:

```
$sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3979/httpd      
$sudo kill 3979
$sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5152/httpd
```

This all worked perfectly before the failed payment, made the company take the server down.

EDIT:
In response to the comment by panther:
I already tried rebooting, but that produced the same result.

There is nothing new in the logs since the reactivation.. last entry is before the server was taken down.

Edit 2:
output of ps aux:

```
$ps aux | grep httpd
root      4995  0.0  0.0   4512  1708 ?        Ss   16:38   0:00 /bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/4371/bin/run-httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5129  0.0  0.0   4512  1668 ?        S    16:38   0:00 /bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/4371/bin/httpd-wrapper -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5152  0.0  0.0  50712  4544 ?        S    16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5153  0.0  0.0 413920  6324 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5154  0.0  0.0 348352  6028 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5155  0.0  0.0 348304  6028 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

This could be a misconfigured nextcloud perhaps?

Comment: What is in the apache log ? Perhaps reboot

Comment: Have by any chanced installed two separate instances of Apache? For instance one from repositories (`apt install apache2`) and one from some other source? Because on Ubuntu the process name should be `apache2`, not `httpd`, if installed from repositories.

Comment: I am quite confident i installed apache with apt-get. Is there a way to verify tis isnt the issue?

Comment: Run `ps aux | grep httpd` and [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: Looks as if apache is running via a snap package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Noticing the problem

I noticed my apache server wasn't working as expected.

```
$sudo service apache2 status

Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4414]:  *
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4430]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net apache2[4430]:  *
Jan 03 16:34:22 vmi120100.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

The line stating "could not bind to address [::]:80" states that another program is using port 80.

## Investigating the problem

To figure out what program uses port 80, i ran netstat.

```
$sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80               :::*                LISTEN      3979/httpd
```

The output told me that process id 3979 with the name httpd is the one using up port 80.

To find out what runs httpd, i used ps aux

```
$ps aux | grep httpd
root      4995  0.0  0.0   4512  1708 ?        Ss   16:38   0:00 /bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/4371/bin/run-httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5129  0.0  0.0   4512  1668 ?        S    16:38   0:00 /bin/sh /snap/nextcloud/4371/bin/httpd-wrapper -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5152  0.0  0.0  50712  4544 ?        S    16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5153  0.0  0.0 413920  6324 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5154  0.0  0.0 348352  6028 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
root      5155  0.0  0.0 348304  6028 ?        Sl   16:38   0:00 httpd -d /snap/nextcloud/4371 -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

I see that it is run from /snap/nextcloud , which means that my nextcloud is the one who is messing about.

## Fix

Further investigation, showed that i had both a snap and a regular install of nextcloud. All i had to do was to remove the snap, and everything was working fine.

If anyone has a similar problem, remember to assess how to resolve the issue. Uninstalling might not be the right option for you.